# Vertically aligning an icon

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have icons. Problem is they do not vertically align to the middle like everything else (text, input). My html structure is something like this:

```
<div class="i_contain_things">
  <div class="i_float_left"><checkbox/></div>some text
  <div class="i_float_right">
    <span class="sprite icn1">my sprite</span>
    <span class="sprite icn2">my sprite</span>
  </div>
</div>

.i_contain_things
{
clear:both;
margin-bottom:10px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.i_float_left
{
padding:0 3px 0 3px;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}

.i_float_right
{
padding:0 3px 0 3px;
float:right;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.sprite
{
display:inline-block;
background: url(../img/icn_sprite_1.png);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.icn1{background-position:0,0}
.icn2{background-position:0,16px}
```

my sprite is always aligned to the bottom, while the checkbox and text are in the middle.

Comment: Have any actual markup to test? Basically I would just suggest adding a bit of a bot margin to the image, or go the line-height css vertical align technique. http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight.html

Comment: Can you use regular html syntax? It'll make it easier to look at. Also can you include some css?

Comment: line-height did nothing, I cannot add a bottom margin, as the height is variable.

Comment: Aepheus, please highlight your code and click the "code" button {}

Comment: There is no background-position in this code sample.  Why are you referring to this as CSS Sprites?

Comment: @ Nick - In lacking background-position, the default would be 0,0 - thus this would work fine. It wouldn't be until you wanted to define the second image that a position would actually be required. Thanks for the vote down 5 months too late. As already stated, the example was missing display style.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work, a span is an inline element so as soon as you remove the text, it will collapse; `height` and `width` won´t do anything.

I´m not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but it seems to me that you need to put your sprite as a background to one of the elements you already have (like `.i_contain_things`), and not put it in a separate element.

If you do need to put it in a separate element, you need to make sure it´s a block level element (for example a `div` or a `span` that's set to `display:block`). That element needs to be positioned where you want it.

Comment: Not putting it in a separate element makes it impossible to use css sprites.

Comment: @Nick - this is untrue, the example would act as a sprite if it had display:block; you could then define other sprite elements using the same background and background position. no addition elements are required.

Comment: We must have a different definition of CSS Sprites.  I thought CSS Sprites were a technique where you place multiple small images into a single larger image and then select the one you want using background-position.

Comment: @Nick Retallack It's a long time ago, but I only wrote that because in the original example, there was no need for a separate element as it was already contained in another element that did not have any additional content AND was a block element already.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  It's the question that is at fault here, not the answers.  I already edited the question anyway.  Sorry for commenting on you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `background-position` property. Like so:

```
sprite { background: url(../img/icn_sprite_1.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

Where the first number is axis-x and the second number is axis-y You can use percentages, pixels, or keywords (right, top, center) to declare the position of the background image.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: backgound-position takes center as keyword, not middle

Comment: You need to use background position to do css sprites.

Comment: @Nick, of course. In this answer I'm just using "Background" as a shorthand declaration. The 50% 50% refers to the background-property.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  What I mean is, if you want to do sprites properly, you already need to use the background position to select the sprite.  You can't then also use the background position to position the background.  However, the person asking the question doesn't seem to know what CSS sprites are either, so this whole thread is confusing me.

Comment: Sorry for adding all these comments.  I'll just edit the original question instead of complaining about the answers.